# How can i convert the big PDF file to excel?

Tags: pdf-generation

I have this file in PDF file which has 2000 records, now i need to count the same number of records in it. I can do it in excel, the question is is there is any way to convert the PDF file into excel, provided i am not having the paid version of adobe PDF viewer

Comment: Yes, there's software that can tear apart a PDF and extract data from them, assuming that the data is in the pdf as actual data, and not just a PICTURE of the data.

Comment: convert it to text then paste it in excel http://convertonlinefree.com/PDFToTXTEN.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, online tools are great, but the best way that i came across is Monarch software, its a data report mining tool, go ahead and try to use it..